# Compare cell data in Column B to all of Column A and turn green when there is a match

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In excel, I have the following:

[image]

I am trying to find the quickest and most user-friendly way to compare columns 2 and 1.

If a name in column 2 (in the format shown below) matches ANY of the cells in Column 1, the cell in Column 1 goes GREEN, indicating that user is PRESENT in Column 2.

I have played around with conditional formatting but would appreciate any direct and efficient solutions.

I was trying to adapt a version of this, but it failed to work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID($A4&" "&$A4,FIND(",",$A4)+2,FIND(",",$A4&" "&$A4,FIND(",",$A4)+2)-FIND(",",$A4)-2)=$B$4:$B$33))
```

where the above formula was added on highlighting the first column and then ensuring the A4 referred to the first item in Column 1 and the B was the first and last item in column 2. As mentioned, this didn't work.

Update

Tried this as well but didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Use COUNTIFS and check if the result is > 0 (green) or =0 (red). Or use ISNUMBER and MATCH.

Comment: @BigBen -could you post a solution with clear instructions so I can verify? Thanks in advance

Comment: the posted answer is the approach I mentioned. `COUNTIF` or `COUNTIFS` work here.

Comment: Thanks - but if you see my update (and screenshot) in question, I tried the posted answer and it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Change the formula to `COUNTIF(B:B,A2)`. You've got a mismatch between the "Applies To" range and the formula.

Comment: Hmm...for a longer list of As and Bs it doesn't work....some errors

Comment: Can you add (yet another) screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer written assuming column1 = column A, and column2 = column B

1. Apply a conditional format on column 1, set up with green background, with the formula `=COUNTIF(B:B, A1)>0`
2. Apply another conditional format on Column 1, set up with red background, formula `=COUNTIF(B:B, A1)=0`

Edit those formulas as necessary so that:

- `B:B` is the address of column 2, the range you're looking in for each name
- `A1` is the address of the first (top-left) cell that the conditional format applies to.

Comment: Thanks so much - What do you mean if column1 is A:A .....?

Comment: see update above. I tried what you suggested, unless I'm doing something wrong, and it didn't work

Comment: I've updated the question a bit, does that make any sense? sorry I can't see your screenshot due to a filter on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can select both columns and do Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cells, Duplicate Values. That would be the easiest way to compare. You can format the cells in the first list with red fill if you want them to be red and set the format for duplicate values with green fill. This will format it in the color scheme you showed. If the name is removed from the second column, the cell will go back to red.

[image]

Comment: This is a good idea, wish I'd thought of that! The only way it could go wrong was if a name was duplicated in either column (e.g. if it appeared twice in column 1 and not at all in column 2) it would still get green highlighted.